# Bootstrap datepicker toggle disable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker and getting an issue.

When I click a day, it works well，but when I click the same day again. The selection gets cancelled

The [boostrap datepicker demo](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)  works well.

I had found the example for bootstrap date picker from the above link.

Comment: Please post your code and/or a demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 6):

It's a known issue. Here is a workaround for this issue.

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/816

jsfiddle the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/antonkruger/fpgseobz/

Once I've tried it, I'll post an update.

**Update:**
Yes it works.

In the defaults @ line 1394, add a new option, allowDeselection

```
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
    allowDeselection: false,
    ...
};
```

In the _toggle_multidate function @ line 1015, modify the "else if (ix !== -1)" statement to:

```
else if (ix !== -1 && this.o.allowDeselection){
   this.dates.remove(ix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue myself so if you still need this. trick is to store the current date in a variable each time a new date is created. If the new date is undefined (empty) update date with the temporary variable. I know its a dirty solution, but hey atleast its working.

I wrote a little fiddle `enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/d86msex1/

Goodluck!

Answer (score -1):

There's now an official way to accomplish this:

```
$element.datepicker('remove');
```

source: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#remove

Comment: This removes the component entirely, it doesn't fix the toggling of an already selected date.